# Sanitize the Spaces

Tags: code-golf

Given some raw HTML, sanitize it by formatting the spaces, as defined below.

### Output rules:

<sup>Like [many](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=xkcd) challenges, this one is inspired by [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2109/).</sup>

1. First, "untag" all tags with nothing but spaces in them. (`<i>te<b>    </b>xt</i>` becomes `<i>te    xt</i>`). If a tag has nothing in it (like `<b></b>`, simply delete it and move on.
2. Next, "push" the spaces to the edge. This means that to push spaces at the edge of the tag outside (so `<b><i> test  </i></b>` becomes `<b><i> test</i>  </b>` after one step).
3. Keep repeating steps 1 and 2 until no new changes happen.
4. Collapse sets of spaces. For example, `<b><i>test</i></b>`   should become `<b><i>test</i></b>`  .
5. Finally, trim the string (this means remove the spaces at the edges, so "  ***a***  " becomes "***a***"). An empty string can be the result.

### Input

The input may be taken as an array of bytes or a string. The only tags will be `<b>`, `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<u>`, and `<em>`, and they may have additional attributes may be in the starting tags (so one starting tag could be `<b data-this-is-an-attribute="true">`. The ending tags, in order, are `</b>`, `</strong>`, `</i>`, `</u>`, and `</em>` and will not have attributes. Closing tags will be in order (so `<b><i></i></b>` works, but `<b><i></b></i>` will never be a test case). There are no newlines in the input.

**Edit: attributes may be in single or double quotes.**

Be sure not to follow any of the rules for the tags, especially the spaces!

```
"<b>  <i> </i></b>" -> "<b>   </b>" -> "   " -> "" (the quotes in this test case are to prevent confusion)
<u> x <em onclick="alert('Hi!')" style="font-size: 50px">kcd </em> comics </u> -> <u>x <em onclick="alert('Hi!')" style="font-size: 50px">kcd</em> comics</u>
<strong>Formatting<i> </i>is <u data-info='test     case'>HA     RD</u></strong>    -> <strong>Formatting is <u data-info='test     case'>HA RD</u></strong>
s p a c     e s -> s p a c e s
one<i> </i>space -> one space
&nbsp; &nbsp; -> &nbsp; &nbsp; (no changes, as we don't consider &nbsp;)
```

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Note: you can use any language to do this challenge; it's just inspired by HTML.

Comment: I assume `<b>` in the ending tags list is a mistake?

Comment: Thanks @Bbrk24, fixed.

Comment: It still says `<b>` in the end tags list, but now `</b>` is a start tag.

Comment: Fixed again! (I'm surprised no one found these issues in the Sandbox.)

Comment: may i assume input wont contain doctype cdata comment, won’t contain script or style tag, and all lt and gt sign are escaped even in quotes?

Comment: May I assume attribute values always warped in double quotes, not single quotes, not w/o quotes?

Comment: Why is `style="font-size: 50px"` gone in the output of the third test case? Also, you may want to expand the explanation of step 5 a bit, since with a regular trim I wasn't expecting `<u> x ... comics </u>` to become `<u>x ... comics</u>`. I assume `<b><i> test</i> </b>` would become `<b><i>test</i></b>` (no spaces left) after step 5?

Comment: Suggested test cases: `"test     case"` -> `"test case"`; `<b>  HA    RD  </b>` -> `<b>HA RD</b>`.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Doctypes aren't *tags*, so they won't occur, but attributes can have single quotes.

Comment: Is `<u> x <em onclick="alert('  </em>')">kcd </em> comics </u>` a valid test case? And what are we supposed to do with the double spaces in the `alert()` argument?

Comment: @Arnauld Test case 3 shows an example with keeping those extra spaces, so yes, that test case is valid.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>106</s> 97 bytes

```
{`<([a-z]+)[^>]*>( )*</\1>
$2
((^|>)[^<]* ) +([^>]*($|<))
$1$3
^((<[^>]+>)*) | ((<[^>]+>)*)$
$1$3
```

Can definitely be golfed some more.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XVBNTwIxFLz3Vzw3q9suISsaL1peYkKUM1c@pJRCGth2sy0JIv997XYlou/SvJnJzOvUymsjBs0tfV82X0tOp6J/mvfYdIHzHCmwnBezAZL0gVC6OGMg@DwHBj0aJTQ9c8ZIOkgfyYJS3oI9ZDmDM1yvaZQ0DdfoFV8hhOHFCo@eFxpJQAIDXjnf4hpbjkRdi/8iB4QjcFWCNXKv5W6YiL2qPc3G@iZjCTj/uVfDZGON7zt9Us/wdF8dE9zJdXBRJYK0pZYuLIdg53xtzRbfbF0KH5rYXtJ0UBxgLbzoa7Oxw6Q7LYwUTiU4fo3LZNT68OLHJyDEQQUCZKQVOGKNupi6SkhF7szKVS/QPfHn10HZn6AMP7qASxsxdzLqyiP/riKx2pZx/hs)

**Explanation:**

Keep executing the replacements until the result no longer changes:

```
{`
```

Step 1: untag all tags that only contain spaces and remove empty tags:

```
<([a-z]+)[^>]*>( )*</\1>
$2
```

Step 4: collapse sets of spaces to a single space, unless they're inside an attribute:

```
((^|>)[^<]* ) +([^>]*($|<))
$1$3
```

Step 5: 'trim' leading/trailing spaces, ignoring the tags:

```
^((<[^>]+>)*) | ((<[^>]+>)*)$
$1$3
```

Comment: I don't think this gives the correct result for `te<b></b>st`.

Comment: @Neil Woops.. That was working in my initial version, but I accidentally broke that case. Should be fixed again.

Comment: @Neil Btw, two questions: 1) Is there a builtin for `[a-z]` outside of Transliterates in Retina? 2) Is there a way to use variables for regex-portions (e.g. the `((<[^>]+>)*)` in my last replacement)? I know this is possible in Perl and Ruby style regexes, but Retina is based on .NET regexes where this unfortunately isn't possible if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Retina only uses .NET regex for matching, so those aren't possible, sorry.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):

File "answer" in line 20:

Step 1, step 4 and step 5

StepError: Steps must be an arithmetic sequence starting at 1 and increasing by 1 each time.`

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 86 bytes

```
{`(<[^/>]+>) 
 $1
 (</.*?>)
$1
^ |<[^/>]+></.*?>| $|( )+|(?<=<[^>]*)((["']).*?\3)
$1$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDNTsMwEITveYolCsRpVcKPuICzFRKCnnstreq4bmU1saPYkQrk3YPdEASIA8IX78x4v125FlYq1p2Sp3X3tiZ0sUpxOcYEAoguAyA0PR9NMQmcWEE7xL3bQtQSSMYtmdLMRbgcJYQswniZuPj52ndFV11HcwSgEoGm0rXmGAS0QTgAFSVoxQvJ91nIClFbEs/kSZyEYOxLIbJwq5WdGPkqbuHmojqEuOcbhxElAtel5MaJBj3uv7SvsJ5lbK3VDh91XTLrfmc3rC7dtAY2zLKJVFudxVYYC/5wZkSMs/ujmD94Dk0/OM75hQl/gP0ABQYqYMCPjwSYT@1rrcSwpqkYF96AvjpTuanuoL@@q3c) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
{`
```

Repeat the following replacements as many times as necessary.

```
(<[^/>]+>) 
 $1
```

Move a space after an open tag to before it.

```
 (</.*?>)
$1
```

Move a space before a close tag to after it.

```
^ |<[^/>]+></.*?>| $|( )+|(?<=<[^>]*)((["']).*?\3)
$1$2
```

Handle all of the remaining cases:

- `^`  Delete leading spaces
- `<[^/>]+></.*?>` Delete empty tags
- `$` Delete trailing spaces
- `( )+|(?<=<[^>]*)((["']).*?\3)` Collapse spaces not inside attributes